# Why custom type of function can only use for declaration?

Tags: c++

Can anyone explain why define type(both of typedef and using) can only for header, but can't use for implement?

```
using myfunc = void();

myfunc test; //this will be okay
myfunc test {} //this is wrong
```

P.S. GCC said ***error: function ‘void test()’ is initialized like a variable*** for `myfunc test {}`

Comment: Oh sorry, I changed it

Comment: Why Visual C++ said typedef cannot use for define?

Comment: typedef and using can be used for both header and implementation. Whatever problem you are having it's something different to what you think it is.

Comment: So how to make it valid?

Comment: @AlanJian That depends entirely on what you are trying to do, which isn't clear to me. Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: I just want to make it a void function called test by integrated type

Comment: `void test_impl(){} myfunc test = test_impl;`

Comment: @MooingDuck Sorry, my compiler said function can't initialized like a variable